# Wordpress: How to show commas on $postcount PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the problem I am faced with. I am working with Wordpress and am using two PHP's to display stats on my site to guests such as the `# total of posts` created and the `# of total comments` on the site. The PHP's working great and shows the current real time #'s, however they're not rendering commas, such as `2,700` in which show as `2700` and say for another example `100,800` which shows as `100800`.

Can anyone tell me how to modify these 2 php's to achieve this?

Here is the posts status PHP codes:

```
<?php
$postcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
echo $postcount;
?>

Here is the comments status php:

<?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments();
echo "" . $comments_count->total_comments . "";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

-Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $postcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
  echo number_format($postcount, 0); 
?>
```

On comments count:

```
<?php
  $comments_count = wp_count_comments();
  echo "" . number_format($comments_count->total_comments, 0) . "";
?>
```

Comment: The ", 0" is too much (=> unnecessary); it's already the default parameter.

Comment: True - it's not required, just force of habit.

Comment: That one works great. How do I achieve this on the 2nd php for comments #?

Comment: @JayJay Updated answer "should" work - I can't see what `$comments_count` echoes out though.

Comment: Yes, working great. You all taught me allot today. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JayJay Don't forget to accept the answer you found most useful (by clicking the tick under the score on the left)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
number_format($postcount);
```

should be enough to show the thousands separators.

For the second use:

```
echo "" . number_format($comments_count->total_comments) . "";
```

Comment: Nice, I got them both working now and understand allot better how to achieve this next time. Thank you all so very much